# QtSpim Character Insertion

Tags: mips, spim

> The program accepts a single-letter keyboard input at a time. The
>   letter inputs must be lower case a through z (no upper-case or
>   non-letter characters allowed; only lower-case letters). Only one
>   letter must be input at a time; make sure that the character is ONLY a
>   lower-case letter.
>
> • In the data declaration, declare an alphabetized
>   string of letters (named “str”), a-z.
>
> • The program must input a
>   character from the keyboard, determine its place in the string, and
>   make a space in the string for this character, inserting it in the
>   proper alphabetical order.
>
> • After the alphabetized string of 26
>   letters, declare a sequence of 30 nulls (using the “.space”
>   directive), as expansion space for the string as you insert characters
>   into the alphabetized list.
>
> • At any point, you can ask to print the
>   current string (i.e., with as many letter inserts as have been made so
>   far) by inputting capital P from the keyboard.
>
> • Finally, this program
>   MUST use a recursive routine to insert the letter in the correct point
>   in the program.

My code so far

```
    .data
 str:   .asciiz"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\n"
 espace:    .space 30
 prompt:    .asciiz "Please enter a lowercase letter \n"
 error1:    .asciiz "Error! Please input a lowercase letter. \n"
 answer:    .asciiz "The alphebetized letters so far are \n"

    .text
 main:  la $s0,0
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,prompt
    syscall
 loop:  li $v0,12
    syscall
    move $t0,$v0
    blt $t0,61,error    #if less than a
    bgt $t0,80,error    #if more than z
    bge $t0,0x50,print  #when user enters P, print
 loop2: lb $t2,str($s0)     #load first byte of string
    bge $t0,$t2,store   #if input char=string char, store it
    addi $s0,$s0,1      #next char in string
    j loop
 store: la  $t0,str+26
    li  $t1,'a'
    sb  $t1,($t0)     # append an 'a' to the string
    sb  $zero,1($t0)  # add a NULL terminator after the 'a'
    sw $t0,str($s0)     #store char in string
    addi $s0,$s0,1 
    j loop
 error: li $v0,4
    la $a0,error1       #print error message
    syscall
    j loop          #jump back to loop
 print: li $v0,4
    la $a0,answer       #print dialogue
    syscall
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,str      #print string
    syscall
```

I just need to know how to write the code so that it inputs the character in the string

Comment: Why the qt label ?

Comment: oh i was writing qtspim and the tags put itself